# is there an alternative to pycurl.FORM_FILE that takes either a string to be sent or a stream object?

Tags: python, http, libcurl, pycurl

I've started using pycurl recently and am currently using the setop pycurl.FORM_FILE. But the data that i want to send is in a string, so it is weird to write a file just so the next method can read it.

So my question is: is there an alternative to pycurl.FORM_FILE that takes either a string to be sent or a stream object (like a file object)?

It would be simmilar to FORM_STREAM from libcurl.

readdata and readfunction won't work for post with multi-part form.

something like this:

```
import pycurl
c = pycurl.Curl()

c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://someurl')
c.setopt(c.FORM_FILE, 'myfile.gz')
c.perform()

c.close()
```

Would become:

```
import pycurl
c = pycurl.Curl()

fobj = open('myfile.gz', 'rb')
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://someurl')
c.setopt(c.FORM_STREAM, fobj)
c.perform()
fobj.close()
c.close()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok found the solution.

The method i was looking for was pycurl.FORM_BUFFER with pycurl.FORM_BUFFERPTR.

Its use can be found in the following test: https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/blob/66f2dec7838ed920a45e57520b95e99928396d93/tests/post_test.py

Warning: if you have an old version of pycurl it might not have this function.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look  at `StringIO` https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html. It will allow you to create a file-like object.

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> f_obj = StringIO.StringIO('foo')
 >>> dir(f_obj)
['__doc__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__module__', 'buf', 'buflist', 'close', 'closed', 'flush', 'getvalue', 'isatty', 'len', 'next', 'pos', 'read', 'readline', 'readlines', 'seek', 'softspace', 'tell', 'truncate', 'write', 'writelines']
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes i want to use StringIO but the StringIO object is like a file object, and the FORM_FILE takes a file name wich it uses to open the file. Therefore, it is impossible to pass the StringIO object as the argument.